# regular expression for all binary strings that include at least two 0s and at least one 1?

Tags: regex, finite-automata

Im thinking it would be (E0*0*EUE1*E)?
where E is the set of my alphabet, with at least 2 0s and at least 1 1

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: never knew that existed, awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
^(.*0.*0.*1.*)|(.*0.*1.*0.*)|(.*1.*0.*0.*)$
```

EDIT
Could be simplified to:

```
^.*(0.*0.*1)|(0.*1.*0)|(1.*0.*0).*$
```

Comment: Why using `^` and `$` anyway? Try `(0.*0.*1)|(0.*1.*0)|(1.*0.*0)`

Comment: If one would want to verify that a string of `1`s and `0`s meets the conditions in the question, a search for `001|01+0|100` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use lookahead, here is how I'd do it: (in PHP free-spacing mode with comments.)

```php
$re = '/
    # Binary strings that include at least two 0s and at least one 1.
    ^                  # Anchor to start of string.
    (?=(?:[^0]*0){2})  # at least two 0s. 
    (?=[^1]*1)         # at least one 1.
    [+\-]?             # Optional leading sign.
    [01]+              # Match string of binary digits.
    $                  # Anchor to end of string.
    /x';
```

Note that you may place any number of lookaheads at the beginning of the string (which work in a logical `AND` manner), to specify multiple logical requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution is wrong, since it will also accept `000000000` where E={0,1}. note that 1* means any number of 1's [including none]

`E* * (0E*0E*1+0E*1E*0+1E*0E*0) * E*` would work: all possible permutations of 0,0,1, and insert E* wherever possible [so you can insert any numbers of characters between/before the required elements]. In regex syntax it is: `.*(0.*0.*1|0.*1.*0|1.*0.*0).*`

Answer (score -3):

(.*00+.*1+.*)|(.* 1+ .* 00+.*)

the above is self explaining

. is any character
+ is one or more